# unable to install wordpress facing error The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, web

need help plz
after receiving  free domain , host from googiehost and
using filezila the connection was successfully estalblished with googie host servers
I copied all wordpress folder files on server through file zilla , 
but whenever i try to access my website for the installation of wordpress (laptechhub.cu.ma/wordpress/)   it shows me error message
I have access of the c-panel and also created a database in mysql and also updated the file ( wp-config-sample.php) in wordpress folder.. with database name, user, password, and the host name ( localhost I wrote there)

one thing i  want to mention i didn't change the name of servers , dnt know where to change them..
whatever i have done so far  i have mentioned above

the exact error is :

Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Have you tried to upload a simple index.php file and try to access it?

Comment: You do know you need to update wp-config.php not wp-config-sample.php? - Maybe take a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install

Comment: yeah i have updated the wp-config-sample into wp-config.php and gave all the necessary database information there..still not working

Comment: i also try to put a simple index.php file ...still its showing me an errorNot Found The requested URL / was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: if I try to access like ftp.laptop-hub.cu.ma then it asks me for username and password and after successful login it took me to the directory page where i can see all the files on my driectory ...including wordpress files in a folder...btw i also tried to put wordpress files in root directory and access it like www.laptech-hub.cu.ma ..still not working... btw thank u for replying to this issue...i am new to web development and stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, the domain isn't accessing files.
Where have you uploaded the files ?
Your files should be uploaded in `public_html` folder.

Many hosting providers like [hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/), [kinsta](https://kinsta.com/), [cloudways](http://cloudways.com) provide 1-click WordPress installation. Try installing from there.